# Is anything like `gem server` for python eggs (`pip server` for instance)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distribute

I need something that takes all my installed eggs (most likely with pip) and, just like `gem server`, runs a local server that shows the documentation (if any) for those installed packages.

This is probably hard to accomplish in a general case, because there are different ways to document python's eggs. I would like something that:

- Uses setuptools/distribute to extract documentation information about the package.
- Integrates with sphinx.
- Defaults to inspect the package's modules (again obtained via setuptools).

Best regards,
Manuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html), but it does not use setuptools and does not integrates with Sphinx.

But it is in the standard library and is too easy to setup:

```
$ python -m pydoc -p 8080
```

Open your browser at http://localhost:8080 and see for yourself.

PS.: The reason I chose to use `python -m pydoc` instead of just `pydoc` is because by default it would not catch packages installed in a virtualenv.
See this old issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/virtualenv/+bug/315990